# How To Get The Html Table Data in Jquery Array?

Tags: jquery, html

How To Extract The Data From The Html Table and store it in jquery Array?

Comment: here is an example: http://jsbin.com/oveva3/1465/edit

Comment: @user2451349 What happen OP you got the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert a html table to a javascript array, you can use something like this.

**Html**

```
<table id="myTableId">
   <tr>
      <td>Row 1 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 - Column 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Row 2 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 - Column 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var tableArray = [];

$("table#myTableId tr").each(function() {
    var rowData = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() { rowData.push($(this).text()); });
        tableArray.push(rowData);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of doing it using [jquery map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

**CODE :**

```
var varObject = $('td').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Now convert it into real array by using [jquery makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) and if you want to check it is valid array use isArray

```
var array = $.makeArray(varObject);
if(jQuery.isArray( array ) === true){ 
    console.log(' valid array ');
 }
```

Here is a [**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/7X67L/14/).